# C++ function doesn't change my argument

Tags: c++, function, vector, visual-studio-2013, arguments

I've recently started programming in Cpp and I came across an issue I couldn't resolve nor find myself an appropriate answer.

I,m interested why, when I pass and argument to a function (fillInArray function)
it doesn't change anything. When in debugger I found out that vectorArray (argument I wanted to pass) doesn't change at all, but pushback method on vector inside this function seems to work, it increments vector size. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated since this problem denies me from moving on with this program.

header.h

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class header
{

private:
    int numberOfBytes = NULL;
    int number;
    int argument;
    vector<int> vectorArray;
    //std::vector<int> vector2;
    //std::vector<int> vector3;

public:

    header();
    ~header();
    void setBytes(int bytes);
    int getBytes();
    void askForBytes();
    void fillInArray(vector<int> someVector);
    void showArray();
    void negateBytes();
    void menu();
    void addArrays();
    void substractArray();
};
```

header.cpp

```
#include "header.h"


header::header()
{
    askForBytes();
    setBytes(number);
    fillInArray(vectorArray);
    //fillInArray(vector2);
    showArray();
    negateBytes();
    showArray();
}


header::~header()
{
}


void header::setBytes(int bytes)
{
    if (bytes % 8 == 0)
    {
        numberOfBytes = bytes;
        cout << "You typed in: " << numberOfBytes << " bytes\n";
    }
    else
        cout << "Wrong argument, number of bytes set to: " << 
        numberOfBytes << " bytes" << endl;

}

void header::askForBytes()
{
    cout << "Plz type in how many bytes: " << endl;
        cin >> number;
}

int header::getBytes()
{
    return numberOfBytes;
}

void header::fillInArray(vector<int> vector)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBytes; i++)
    {
        vector.push_back( rand() % 2);
    }

}

void header::showArray()
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vectorArray.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << vectorArray[i] << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void header::negateBytes()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBytes; i++)
    {
        if (vectorArray[i] == 0)
            vectorArray[i] = 1;
        else
            vectorArray[i] = 0;
    }
}

/*void header::menu()
{
    cout << "Type argument to do stuff: " << endl << 
        "1 to negate single vector\n 2 to add two vectors\n 3 to minus two vectors\n";
    cin >> argument;
    switch (argument)
    {
    case 1: negateBytes();
        showArray(vector);
        break;
    case 2: addArrays();
        showArray(vector);
        break;
    case 3: substractArray();
        showArray(vector);
        break;
    default: cout << "Wrong argument";
    }
}*/

void header::addArrays()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < getBytes(); i++)
    {
        //if ((vector[i] && vector2[i]) == 1)
        //  vector3.push_back(0);
    //  else if ((vector[i] == 1 && vector2[i] == 0) || (vector[i] == 0 && vector2[i] == 1))
        //  vector3.push_back(1);
    //  else vector3.push_back(0);
    }
}

void header::substractArray()
{
}
```

zadanie1.cpp  =   main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"

void showText()
{
    cout << "text";
}

int main()
{
    header head;

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I've also commented out some variables and functions that I will be building later on.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a reference parameter `void fillInArray(vector<int>& someVector);`

Comment: You are filling a copy of `vector` every time you use `fillInArray`. That's why you should pass it by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void fillInArray(vector<int> someVector);
```

Your function takes a vector by value. This means the function gets a *copy* of the vector you pass to it. It can operate on that copy, but those changes aren't visible outside.

You should be passing a reference if you want that function to be able to modify the caller's vector:

```
void fillInArray(vector<int>& someVector);
```

(Same change needs to be made in the function definition.)

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked for me, sorry for that newbie mistake. I'm coming from java and didn't know about that. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an argument by copy, you should not wonder why the callee fails to change the object copied:
It never knew about it.

C++ has constant references to avoid copies (`const T&`), rvalue-references to enable moving (`T&&`), and lvalue-references to enable modification of the passed argument (`T&`).
(Be aware what loks like an rvalue-reference in a template might be a forwarding-reference.)

Of course, you can go the C-route and pass by pointer too.